# When to use int vs. char for buffers when copying binary files?

Tags: c, file-io, binary, buffer

So I was given a problem that states the following:

*Write a void function to copy a binary file into another file, 100 bytes at a time. The function receives the two FILE pointers (src and dest) as arguments.*

I wrote the solution using an array of type integers but I see that some of the other solutions out there use character arrays. Is there a standard to know of when to use an interger array vs. a character array the dealing with binary files.

For example:

```
void copy(FILE *src, FILE *dest)
{
    int buffer[SIZE];
    int ret;

    while((ret = fread(buffer, sizeof(int), 100, src)) > 0)
    {
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(int), ret, dest);
    }
    return;
}
```

should copy just fine as binary files are obviously just represented by bits which consists of 2 integers (0,1). Why would you need to use a character array when copying binary files?

Comment: File would have a stream of bytes, its upto your application how they interpret it whether they are ints,long ints or a user defined data structures

Comment: 100 ints is not 100 bytes.

Comment: @Pras right but why would you use a character array for a buffer if the stream of bytes being transferred to the buffer and then to the new file is still in integer form? thats my confusion right there

Comment: "binary files are obviously just 2 integers (0,1)" -- Huh? Binary files are composed of bytes, and a `char` is 1 byte.

Comment: What would happen if there were an odd number of bytes in the file?  You would lose data if you used `int` to hold the data read.

Comment: @DavidBowling I should clarify.. binary is made up of only 2 integers: 0 and 1. Should have been more specific.

Comment: @ConnorBrereton = They are call bits not integers. Computers work on bytes. Use char. Integers are a multiple of bytes, typically 4

Comment: @EdHeal bits are represented by the following integers: 1 & 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Usually people just use `char []` unless there's special requirement. Actually APIs like `fread()`, `fwrite()` are using `char []` (actually `void *`).
2. It's OK (but a bit weird) to use `int []` but your task requires "*100 bytes at a time*" so you should `fread(buffer, sizeof(int), 100 / sizeof(int), src)` (This is not convinient **if the file size is not a  multiple of 4** <sup>[1]</sup>. Also note that **this may not work** if `sizeof(int) == 8`.) or `fread(buffer, 1, 100, src)` (then you're just using `int []` as `char []`).

<sup>[1]</sup> I suppose `sizeof(int) == 4` which is the most common case.

Comment: This is a very very helpful explanation. Thank you very much. I now understand that its best to just use char as a standard.